# How does scope() method work in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive, which has an isolated scope. Somehow, when I try to get scope from the directive's element, it gives me controller's scope, instead of the isolated scope.

What's wrong with my code? Who can explain how does scope() method works?

This is my js code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .directive('component',function(){
        return {
            restrict:'EA',
            replace:false,
            scope:{
                "model":"="
            },
            template:'<div>{{model.name}}</div>',
            link:function($scope,element,attrs){
                element.bind('click',function(event){
                    console.log("element scope id->", element.scope().$id );
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.myModel = {
            name:"Click me, to see scope's id in console"
        };
        console.log("controller scope id->", $scope.$id);
    });
```

and the markup:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <component selectable model="myModel"></component>
 </div>
```

[DEMO is here](http://jsfiddle.net/50qp7yq3/)

Comment: You dont need to get the scope from the element, replace `element.scope()` with `$scope`.

Comment: And "model" binding just does not seem to be creating any additional isolated scopes. that is why you receive component's scope.

Comment: @haki Yeah, I know it. But I need to retrieve the scope from the *element*. This is must.

Comment: **component** element is within the scope of the **myApp**. The innerhtml of **component** is in the isolated scope.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
console.log("element scope id->", element.scope().$id );
```

To this:

```
console.log("element scope id->", $scope().$id );
```

If you do want to get the scope from the element, do this:

```
console.log("element scope id->", element.isolateScope().$id );
```

Notice the call to isolateScope. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods

Answer (score 0):

In your directive you have made private scope by creating it's own scope object *scope: {model:'='}*. That's why element.scope() is actually it's parent's scope.

Here are few facts:

- directive's $scope().$parent = element.scope()
- Parent cannot access child's scope. Though there are some work arounds like element.scope().$$childHead, but it's not recommended, and it doesnot work all the time.
- To communicate with parent to child you can use $scope().$broadcast('event-name', param1, param2) from parent, and catch the event from child using $scope.$on('event-name', function($parentScope, param1, param2){...})
- You can communicate from child to parent using $scope().$parent.methodName() to directly call parent's method or access parent's model, or using event firing like $scope().$emit('event-name', param1, param2), and catch the event from parent using $scope.$on('event-name', function($childScope, param1, param2){...})

Hope this will help.